# Edge detection of foot in opencv

Tags: opencv, edge-detection

I'm trying to find the outline of a foot in the picture, and draw contours. I've tried various methods, but am unable to detect the edges. I was wondering what kind of techniques I could use to get better results.

Any help would be appreciated.
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyVIs.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OM0F.png)

Comment: You should really 1) tune the parameters and 2) normalize correctly the output for a correct visualization, for every approach you tried

Comment: Thanks, I'll try different parameter values then.

Answer (score 0):

[Foot Type Measurement System by Image Processing by Xu Chang](https://www.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/independent_studies_projects/image_foot_type/foot_type_measurement_report.pdf):

"First ... generate another picture which only contains the edge information. We use the built-in function cvCanny() to achieve the result. Next, we use cvFindContours() to extract the whole contours in edge image."

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)